# Explain ListBuffer(comp: _*)

Tags: scala

I've encountered this code :

```
ListBuffer(comp: _*)
```

comp is of type `List[String]`

What is `ListBuffer(comp: _*)` achieving ? Specifically `comp: _*`  ?

Comment: You could use [symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=scala+_*) to search for such symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListBuffer` apply method takes a vararg parameter of some type `A`. In order to pass it some sequence of value, for example a `List`, without explicit extraction of values you can use `_*` which means: take all values from this sequence (`comp` in your case) and pass them into this function as an argument.